# Events manager in TOAD for MySQL

Tags: mysql, events, toad

Does anybody now how to find and view/browse the existing scheduler events in TOAD for MySQL, or how to find them with SQL as they are really metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I always use [SHOW EVENTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-events.html) to see what the scheduler has up its sleeve for a given schema.

Example:

```
show events in my_schema;
```

Comment: Just tried it and it works!, Thanks! (weird that Toad doesn't have that module...?) thanks again Tom.Leo